# What do I do next when trying to find the derivative of this fraction?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, solution-verification

I'm trying to find the derivative of this equation: $-\frac{3(x-6)}{2\sqrt{9-x}}$

The quotient rule: $\frac{d}{dx}[\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}]=\frac{g(x)f'(x)-f(x)g'(x)}{(g(x))^2}$ where $g(x)$ and $f(x)$ are functions.

So I take out the constants and I'm left with $\frac{-3}{2}\frac{d}{dx}[\frac{(x-6)}{\sqrt{9-x}}]$.

$f(x)$ is $(x-6)$ and $g(x)$ is $(9-x)^{1/2}$. This is what it expands to:

$$\frac{-3}{2} \left[\frac{(9-x)^{1/2}\frac{d}{dx}[x-6]-(x-6)\frac{d}{dx}[(9-x)^{1/2}]}{((9-x)^{1/2})^2}\right]$$

After simplifying, I get:

$$\frac{-3}{2}\left[\frac{(9-x)^{1/2}(1)-(x-6)[(\frac{1}{2})(9-x)^{-1/2}(-1)]}{9-x}\right]$$

$$\frac{-3}{2}\left[\frac{\sqrt{9-x}-(x-6)(-1)}{2(9-x)\sqrt{9-x}}\right]$$

$$\frac{-3}{2}\left[\frac{\sqrt{9-x}+x-6}{2(9-x)\sqrt{9-x}}\right]$$

$$\frac{-3\sqrt{9-x}-3x+18}{4(9-x)\sqrt{9-x}} \text{ ??}$$

What did I do wrong? Wolfram Alpha says the answer is: $\frac{3(x-12)}{4(9-x)^{3/2}}$

Comment: $\text{“}\dfrac d {dx}\text{''}$ in front of $\text{“}\frac{(9-x)^{1/2} \frac{d}{dx}[x-6]-(x-6) \frac{d}{dx} [(9-x)^{1/2}]}{((9-x)^{1/2})^2}\text{''}$ should not be there. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: In what way? the derivative of (x-6) is 1 and the derivative of (9-x)^1/2 is (1/2)(9-x)^-1/2(-1). And the denominator would be (9-x)^(2/2) which is just (9-x).

Comment: When you multiplied the numerator and denominator by $\sqrt{9-x}$, you forgot to multiply the first term.

Comment: I've just deleted the thing that should not have been there.

Comment: Actually, I didn't multiply by the squareroot of 9-x, I moved it to the denominator because it was negative. Now I realized that I shouldn't have done that because it would be a fraction on the numerator.

Comment: Here's the right way to move something to the denominator because it is what you called "negative": $\displaystyle \frac{A+BC^{-1}}{D} = \frac{AC+B}{DC}$.  This actually does amount to multiplying the numerator and the denominator by $C\vphantom{\frac\sum\sum}$. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Until here: $$\frac{-3}{2}[\frac{(9-x)^{1/2}(1)-(x-6)[(\frac{1}{2})(9-x)^{-1/2}(-1)]}{9-x}]$$ you're good. This simplifies to: $$-\frac{3}{2}\left[\frac{\sqrt{9-x}+ \frac{1}{2}(x-6)\frac{1}{\sqrt{9-x}}}{9-x}\right] = -\frac{3}{2}\left[\frac{\color{red}{(9-x)}+ \frac{1}{2}(x-6)}{(9-x)^{3/2}}\right] = -\frac{3}{4} \frac{18-2x+x-6}{(9-x)^{3/2}},$$which is readily seen to agree with Wolfram's answer. Where I pointed in red, you kept $\color{blue}{\sqrt{9-x}}$.

---

More detailed:

$$\begin{align}\frac{\sqrt{9-x}+ \frac{1}{2}(x-6)\frac{1}{\sqrt{9-x}}}{9-x} \cdot\frac{\color{red}{\sqrt{9-x}}}{\color{blue}{\sqrt{9-x}}} &= \frac{\left(\sqrt{9-x}+ \frac{1}{2}(x-6)\frac{1}{\sqrt{9-x}}\right)\color{red}{\sqrt{9-x}}}{(9-x)\color{blue}{\sqrt{9-x}}} \\ &= \frac{\sqrt{9-x}\color{red}{\sqrt{9-x}}+\frac{1}{2}(x-6)\require{cancel}\cancel{\frac{1}{\sqrt{9-x}}}\cancel{\color{red}{\sqrt{9-x}}}}{(9-x)^{3/2}} \\ &= \frac{9-x+\frac{1}{2}(x-6)}{(9-x)^{3/2}}\end{align}$$

Comment: Wait, so how do the denominator become to the power of 3/2? I see what you're saying now for the numerator because I forgot to multiply the top by the squareroot of 9-x.

Comment: Remember that: $$(9-x)\sqrt{9-x} = (9-x)(9-x)^{1/2} = (9-x)^{1+ \frac{1}{2}} = (9-x)^{3/2}$$

Comment: And yes, that's pretty much the mistake. Your problem wasn't with calculus itself, it was just an algebraic manipulation. It happens.

Comment: Wait, so If I want the numerators to have the same denominator, I also multiply the denominator by the same denominator? In this case, multiply all by the square root of 9-x?

Comment: You can think of it this way: you're multiplying everything by: $$1 = \frac{\color{red}{\sqrt{9-x}}}{\color{blue}{\sqrt{9-x}}}.$$Then $\color{red}{\sqrt{9-x}}$ go to the numerator and simplyfies some stuff, and $\color{blue}{\sqrt{9-x}}$ stays in the denominator to later become $(9-x)^{3/2}$.

Comment: Okay, so it's not about getting the common denominator on the top then? Because wouldn't the right side on the numerator have a denominator of $$\frac{1}{2\sqrt{9-x}}$$? Since 1/2 is a fraction. Why aren't I multiplying by that instead of $\sqrt{9-x}$?

Comment: I added more details in the answer, hope it helps.

Comment: You forgot to multiply by 2 on the edit, otherwise you wouldn't get 18-2x like you did. OHHHH NOW I SEE. You're actually multiplying by $2\sqrt{9-x}$ which leaves a 2 in the denominator and 18-2x on the numerator. Got it. Thanks!!!!!!!!!